# ML Models: How to handle categorical feature with over 1000 unique values

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I am trying to build an ML Classification model on a data set that contains quite a few categorical columns. However, few of them have over 1000 unique values. I am concerned that if I run one-hot encoding or pandas get dummies on them, it will simply result in too many features to work with.

So, I tried to find the top N unique values that account for, say, 90% of the underlying data and group the rest of them under say, 'Other' or 'miscellaneous'. But that's making the 'Other' or 'miscellaneous' value as the most prominent one. I am concerned that this might skew the model/results. Any pointers as to how I should handle such a scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right suggestion, but what if you could delete data/rows related to the values with very less frequency? For instance, these values appear only once/twice in your data set?

Comment: Yeah, i agree with you. However, if i start doing that with all my categorical columns with too many unique values, im afraid i might be deleting a considerable chunk of the data.

Comment: Can you provide a sample ?

Answer (score 2):

If necessary, there are other methods of encoding categorical features:

- Label encoding (might need some judgement regarding implied ordering)
- Target encoding
- Hashing trick

A handy `python` package is Category Encoders: [link](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/)

I would suggest first investigating if your model needs categorical variables to be encoded - `lightgbm` and `catboost` are examples of ML algorithms which support categorical variables.

Comment: Your link does not work. I believe you've meant this package https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders